# Find html control in gridview rowdatabound event in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, rowdatabound

In asp.net we can find HTML standard control using

```
(HtmlInputControlName)e.Item.FindControl("control_id");
```

My question is that can I find paragraph HTML tag

```
<p id="p_id" runat="server">
```

If yes, than what will be control name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use `HtmlGenericControl`

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
    HtmlGenericControl p = e.Row.FindControl("p_id") as HtmlGenericControl;
    p.InnerText = "It works!";
}
```